# Bash script to find new numerical value row wise

Tags: awk

I have the following example

```
    # Sequence                 6 S   TTHTSTAQR   0.687
    # Sequence                 7 T   THTSTAQRS   0.562
    # Sequence                11 S   TAQRSSKYP   0.960
    # Sequence                11 S   TAQRSSKYP   0.711
    # Sequence                12 S   AQRSSKYPT   0.996
    # Sequence                12 S   AQRSSKYPT   0.684
```

My desired output file is

```
    # Sequence                 6 S   TTHTSTAQR   0.687
    # Sequence                 7 T   THTSTAQRS   0.562
    # Sequence                11 S   TAQRSSKYP   0.960
    # Sequence                12 S   AQRSSKYPT   0.996
```

How to do that?

I tried with this

```
    awk -F, '!seen[$3]++' tmp > out
```

But unable to process it.

Thank you for your support in advance

Answer (score 3):

This

```
awk -F, '!seen[$3]++' tmp > out
```

does instruct GNU `AWK` to treat `,` as field separators, whilst

```
# Sequence                 6 S   TTHTSTAQR   0.687
# Sequence                 7 T   THTSTAQRS   0.562
# Sequence                11 S   TAQRSSKYP   0.960
# Sequence                11 S   TAQRSSKYP   0.711
# Sequence                12 S   AQRSSKYPT   0.996
# Sequence                12 S   AQRSSKYPT   0.684
```

does not have `,` at all. Default (zero-or-more whitespace characters) should work in your use case, please first do

```
awk '{print $3}' tmp
```

if it does output column which you want to deduplicate on, then

```
awk '!seen[$3]++' tmp
```

should do what you want, if not you need to first adjust column number.

Comment: Thank you! Actually that "-F" was creating the problem, removing that "-F" fulfill the requirement..

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak program as follows to get awk to do the deed:

```
awk '{if(!seen[$3]++) print $0}' input.txt
```

If the input is sorted by column $3 then you can get away with just storing the last column value:

```
awk '{if(v != $3) {print $0; v=$3}}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Allan! Actually my requirement gets fulfill by removing the "-F" flag.